# How do I correct my Breadth First Search?

Tags: c++, bots, artificial-intelligence, breadth-first-search

I've been trying to solve the following AI problem :

https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/botclean/problem

Here's my code for the same :

```
#include<iostream>
#include<vector>
#include <queue>

using namespace std;


// searches and checks if the coordinates are previously visited or not
bool search_(vector<vector<int>> check, vector<int> coords){
    
    int len = check.size();
    
    for(int i = 0; i < len; i++){
        if(check[i][0] == coords[0] && check[i][1] == coords[1]){
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}

vector<int> bfs(vector<string> board, int r, int c, int n){
    
    queue<vector<int>> q;
    vector<int> initial, mt;
    initial.push_back(r);
    initial.push_back(c);
    
    mt.push_back(-1);
    mt.push_back(-1);    
    
    q.push(initial);
    
    vector<vector<int>> check_arr;
    if(search_(check_arr, initial)){
        check_arr.push_back(initial);
    }

    vector<int> last;
    vector<int> neighbour1, neighbour3;
    vector<int> neighbour2, neighbour4;
    int n1 = 0, n2 = 0, n3 = 0, n4 = 0;
    
    while(1){
        if(q.empty()){
            return mt;
        }
        
        last = q.back();
        q.pop();
        
        if(board[last[0]][last[1]] == 'd'){
            return last;
        }
        
        if(search_(check_arr, last)){
            check_arr.push_back(last);
        }
   
        
        // Neighbours
        n1 = 0; n2 = 0; n3 = 0; n4 = 0;
        neighbour1.push_back(last[0]);
        neighbour1.push_back(last[1]+1);
        
        
        if(last[1]+1 < n){
            n1 = 1;
        }
        
        if(board[neighbour1[0]][neighbour1[1]] == 'd' && search_(check_arr, neighbour1) && last[1]+1 < n){
            return neighbour1;
        }
        
        neighbour2.push_back(last[0]+1);
        neighbour2.push_back(last[1]);
        
        if(last[0]+1 < n){
            n2 = 1;
        }

        if(board[neighbour2[0]][neighbour2[1]] == 'd' && search_(check_arr, neighbour2) && last[0]+1 < n){
            return neighbour2;
        }
        
        neighbour3.push_back(last[0]);
        neighbour3.push_back(last[1]-1);
        
        if(last[1]-1 >= 0){
            n3 = 1;
        }
        
        if(board[neighbour3[0]][neighbour3[1]] == 'd' && search_(check_arr, neighbour3) && last[1]-1 >=0){
            return neighbour3;
        }
        
        neighbour4.push_back(last[0]-1);
        neighbour4.push_back(last[1]);
        
        if(last[0]-1 >= 0){
            n4 = 1;
        }

        if(board[neighbour4[0]][neighbour4[1]] == 'd' && search_(check_arr, neighbour4) && last[0]-1 >= 0){
            return neighbour4;
        }
        
        if(search_(check_arr, neighbour1) && n1 == 1){
            check_arr.push_back(neighbour1);
            q.push(neighbour1);
        }
        if(search_(check_arr, neighbour2) && n2 == 1){
            check_arr.push_back(neighbour2);
            q.push(neighbour2);
        }
        if(search_(check_arr, neighbour3) && n3 == 1){
            check_arr.push_back(neighbour3);
            q.push(neighbour3);
        }
        if(search_(check_arr, neighbour4) && n4 == 1){
            check_arr.push_back(neighbour4);
            q.push(neighbour4);
        }
        
        neighbour1.clear();
        neighbour2.clear();
        neighbour3.clear();
        neighbour4.clear();
        last.clear();
    }
    
    return mt;
}

void next_move(int posr, int posc, vector <string> board) {
    //add logic here
    
    // Use BFS to determine the closest dirty position
    vector<int> next_pos = bfs(board, posr, posc, board.size());
    
    // Move towards it
    if(next_pos[0] - posr > 0){
        cout<<"DOWN\n";
        return;
    }
    else{
        if(next_pos[0] != posr){
            cout<<"UP\n";
            return;
        }
    }
    
    if(next_pos[1] - posc > 0){
        cout<<"RIGHT\n";
        return;
    }
    else{
        if(next_pos[1] != posc){
            cout<<"LEFT\n";
            return;
        }
    }
    
    if(next_pos[0] == posr && next_pos[1] == posc){
        cout<<"CLEAN\n";
        return;
    }
}

int main(void) {
    int pos[2];
    vector <string> board;
    cin>>pos[0]>>pos[1];
    for(int i=0;i<5;i++) {
        string s;cin >> s;
        board.push_back(s);
    }
    next_move(pos[0], pos[1], board);
    return 0;
}
```

Basically, I'm correctly able to identify if my neighbors are dirty or not. But it isn't working beyond that range.
Kindly help me out here. I think I'm wrong in my BFS somewhere.
The answer is right when the dirty bits are neighbors of my bot. But when they aren't, the answer is not printed at all.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I found my error
I was getting a segmentation error near this line :

```
'''
    if(board[neighbour3[0]][neighbour3[1]] == 'd' && search_(check_arr, neighbour3) && last[1]-1 >=0){
        return neighbour3;
'''
```

The reason is neighbour3 isn't a neighbor.
So compiler is unable to check the condition `board[neighbour3[0]][neighbour3[1]] == 'd'` and this showing segmentation error.
I changed that to :

```
    '''
    if(last[1]-1 >=0 && board[neighbour3[0]][neighbour3[1]] == 'd' && search_(check_arr, neighbour3)){
        return neighbour3;
'''
```

Then it worked correctly :)

Answer (score -1):

I don't have too long right now to play around with your code, but I believe this could have to do with the fact that with each iteration of the while loop you call.

```cpp
last = q.back();
q.pop();
```

If you check [the C++ documentation for std::queue](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/queue), you will see that `q.push(...)` pushes an item to the *front* of the queue, `q.last()` accesses the *last* item in a queue, and `q.pop()` pops an item from the *front* of the queue. This is problematic in your code because with each iteration, you are popping an item that you may have not checked. The correct way to do this for your BFS would be

```cpp
toCheck = q.pop();
```

And then check the `toCheck` variable with every loop. Hope this helps!

Comment: You mean `q.back()`.